# How can you make an absolute positioning in css to adjust after the text modification?

Tags: html, css

For example I saw this web-site https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/. On that splash-page you can see a lot of images with position absolute. When you go to inspect element and you modify the content, let's say of the first image(I mean adding more text), the image below will adapt automatically.

How to do it so?

Comment: please, provide your code or show the result of your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses jQuery Masonry plugin to create a grid. That is the reason elements are positioned absolutely and why they react to window resize.

Comment: I've been trying to do that using float or absolute .. but no luck . Thank you for your answer .

Comment: There is no way to create a bricks layout with css, when all elements may have different heights and when we need a responsive layout, that's why Masonry was made first place. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plugin called masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/